# Issue with periodically discrepancies in cufft-fftw complex to real transformations

Tags: cuda, fft, c99, fftw

For my thesis, I have to optimize a special MPI-Navier Stokes-Solver program with CUDA. The original program uses FFTW for solving several PDEs. In detail, several upper triangle matrices are fourier tranformed in two dimensions, but handled as one dimensional arrays. For the moment, I'm struggling with parts of the original code: (N is always set to 64)

Original:

```
//Does the complex to real in place fft an normalizes
void fftC2R(double complex *arr) {
  fftw_execute_dft_c2r(plan_c2r, (fftw_complex*)arr, (double*)arr);
  //Currently ignored: Normalization
  /*  for(int i=0; i<N*(N/2+1); i++)
arr[i] /= (double complex)sqrt((double complex)(N*N));*/
}

void doTimeStepETDRK2_nonlin_original() {
      //calc velocity
      ux[0] = 0;
      uy[0] = 0;

      for(int i=1; i<N*(N/2+1); i++) {
         ux[i] =  I*kvec[1][i]*qvec[i] / kvec[2][i];
         uy[i] = -I*kvec[0][i]*qvec[i] / kvec[2][i];
      }

      fftC2R(ux);
      fftC2R(uy);

      //do some stuff here...
      //...
      return;
}
```

Where ux and uy are allocated as (double complex arrays):

```
ux = (double complex*)fftw_malloc(N*(N/2+1) * sizeof(double complex));
uy = (double complex*)fftw_malloc(N*(N/2+1) * sizeof(double complex));
```

The fft-plan is created as:

```
plan_c2r = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(N, N,(fftw_complex*) qvec, (double*)qvec, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

Where qvec is allocated the same way like ux and uy and has data type double complex.

Here are the relevant parts of the CUDA code:

```
NN2_VecSetZero_and_init<<<block_size,grid_size>>>();
cudaSafeCall(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
cudaSafeCall(cudaGetLastError());

int err = (int)cufftExecZ2D(cu_plan_c2r,(cufftDoubleComplex*)sym_ux,(cufftDoubleReal*)sym_ux);

if (err != CUFFT_SUCCESS ) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return;
}

err = (int)cufftExecZ2D(cu_plan_c2r,(cufftDoubleComplex*)sym_uy,(cufftDoubleReal*)sym_uy);

if (err != CUFFT_SUCCESS ) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return;
}

//do some stuff here...
//...
return;
```

Where sim_ux and sim_uy are allocated as:

```
cudaMalloc((void**)&sym_ux, N*(N/2+1)*sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));
cudaMalloc((void**)&sym_uy, N*(N/2+1)*sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));
```

The initialization of the relevant cufft parts looks like

```
if (cufftPlan2d(&cu_plan_c2r,N,N, CUFFT_Z2D) != CUFFT_SUCCESS){
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return -1;
}

if (cufftPlan2d(&cu_plan_r2c,N,N, CUFFT_D2Z)  != CUFFT_SUCCESS){
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return -1;
}

if ( cufftSetCompatibilityMode ( cu_plan_c2r , CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_FFTW_ALL) != CUFFT_SUCCESS ) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return -1;
}

if ( cufftSetCompatibilityMode ( cu_plan_r2c , CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_FFTW_ALL) != CUFFT_SUCCESS ) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return -1;
}
```

So I use full FFTW compatibility and I call every function with the FFTW calling patterns.
When I run both versions, I receive almost equal results for ux and uy (sim_ux and sim_uy). But at periodically positions of the arrays, Cufft seems to ignore these elements, where FFTW sets the real part of these elements to zero and calculates the complex parts (the arrays are too large to show them here). The stepcount, for which this occurs, is N/2+1. So I believe, I didn't completely understand fft-padding theory between Cufft and FFTW.
I can exclude any former discrepancies between these arrays, until Cufft-executions are called. So any other arrays of the code above are not relevant here.
My question is: am I too optimistic in using almost 100% of the FFTW calling style? Do I have to handle my arrays before the ffts? The Cufft documentation says, I'd have to resize the data input and output arrays. But how can I do this, when I'm running inplace transformations? I really wouldn't like to go too far distant from the original code and I don't want to use any more copy instructions for each fft call, because memory is limited and arrays should remain and processed on gpu as long as possible.

I'm thankful for every hint, critical statement or idea!

My configuration:

- Compiler: gcc 4.6 (C99 Standard)
- MPI-Package: mvapich2-1.5.1p1 (shouldn't play a role because of reduced single processing debug mode)
- CUDA-Version: 4.2
- GPU: CUDA-arch-compute_20 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 570)
- FFTW 3.3

Answer (score 1):

once i had to do with CUFFT the only solution I got to work was with exclusive usage of "cu_plan_c2c" - there are easy transformations between real and complex arrays:

-filling complex part with 0 for emulating cu_plan_r2c

-use atan2 (not atan) on the complex result to emulate cu_plan_c2r

Sorry for not pointing you to any better solution, but this is how I ended up solving this problem. Hope you are not getting into any hard toruble with low memory cpu-sided....

Comment: Thank you! I already tried this way. For this special problem, I found out, that these padding positions have no influence on my further final results, because of inverse operations for each of these FFTs just right before the calculation of the final output. But I was faced with a quite similar problem again while using cufftPlanMany for batched inplace C2R FFTs. Here it seems, cufft has problems to recognize, that I want to use it inplace and makes strange memory corruptions due to padding. I'm going to check out your way for this problem again.

Comment: As far as I remember this was my workaround for batched calculations - so this might help.